# Split and Save data in JS Array using ASP.NET (C#)

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I've this piece of code:

(I want to get the tags and insert them in an JS array that will write in HTML page, but i cant get the tags properly can you tell me whats wrong, or help me doing this, i've searched plenty of solutions but none that works here, TAGS are splited by comma)

**ASP.NET**

```
private void Play(List<string> arraySrc, List<string> arrayTitle, List<string> arrayImage, List<string> arrayTags)
        {
            ...
            string[] tags = arrayTags.ToArray();
            string[] split;
            foreach (string item in tags)
            {
                if (item.IndexOf(',') != -1)
                {
                    split = item.Split(',');
                    foreach (string s in split)
                    {
                        ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("arrayTags", String.Concat("\"<span class=label>", s, "</span>\" "));
                    }
                }
                ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("arrayTags", String.Concat("\"<span class=label>", item, "</span>\" "));
            }
         }
```

**JS**

```
function playList () {
    disabled();
    $("#img").attr("src", "image/no-music.png");
    for (var i = 0; i < arraySrc.length; i++) {
        $("#tab1 ul").append("<li>" + (i + 1) + ". <a href='javascript:loadMusic(\"" + arraySrc[i] + "\", \"" + arrayTitle[i] + "\", \"" + arrayImage[i] + "\", \"" + arrayTags[i] + "\"); selected(" + i + ");'>" + arrayTitle[i] + "</a></li>");
    };
}
function loadMusic (musica, title, image, tags) {
    enabled();
    var audio = $("#player");      

    $("#tags").empty();

    $("#tags").append(tags);

    $("#player").attr("src", musica);
    $("#title").text(title);
    $("#img").attr("src", image);
    $("#tags span").addClass("label-info");
    /****************/
    audio[0].pause();
    audio[0].load(); //suspends and restores all audio element
    audio[0].play();
}
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of the Javascript you want to see as the output? This is where I would recommend you start working on the problem, anyway. Start with the desired output, and work backwards.

Comment: if writing all the tags on the page is all you want to do, why RegisterArrayDeclaration? directly write it to the page

Comment: but the tags are saved in database

Comment: so what? you can create a Webmethod and retrieve all your tags through ajax

Comment: I sort of see where you're going, but what does the Javascript array that you are hoping to generate need to look like? I.e., `var arr = [ { ElementName1 : 'value', ElementName2 : 'value' }, { ... } ];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are doing it in a wrong way.

firstly, you are declaring a javascript array object in a loop, that means, you are declaring an array with same name multiple times. avoid that.

secondly, you should assign comma separated string values to your array to initialize.

so basically, you declare an array in javascript through server side like this.

```
ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("arrayName","1,2,3,4");
or
ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("arrayName","\"One\",\"Two\",\"Three\"");
```

Therefore, the notion is, create the values (comman separated strings) for your array, inside the loop, and then after the loop, Register an array with this created value.

hence do it like this:

```
private void Play(List<string> arraySrc, List<string> arrayTitle, 
                   List<string> arrayImage, List<string> arrayTags)
{
    ...
    string[] tags = arrayTags.ToArray();
    string[] split;
    string aT="arrayTags";
    string aV=string.empty;
    foreach (string item in tags)
    {
      if (item.IndexOf(',') != -1)
      {
         split = item.Split(',');
         foreach (string s in split)
         {
            aV +="\""+ String.Concat("<span class=label>", s, "</span>"))+"\",";
         }
      }
    }
    aV = aV.SubString(0,av.Length-2);//drop the last trailing comma
    ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration(aT,aV);
}
```

I've not tested it, watch out for string concatenation, but that is how you should go about it.